# How can I ensure that a process runs in a specific physical CPU core and thread?

Tags: linux, affinity

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664668/how-to-force-two-process-to-run-on-the-same-cpu) asks about ensuring two processes run on the same CPU.  Using `sched_setaffinity` I can limit a process to a number of logical CPUs, but how can I ensure that these are mapped to specific physical CPUs and threads?

I expect that the mapping would be:

0 - CPU 0 thread 0
1 - CPU 0 thread 1
2 - CPU 1 thread 0
3 - CPU 1 thread 1
etc...

where the number on the left is the relevant CPU used in `sched_setaffinity`.

However, when I tried to test this, it appeared that this is not necessarily the case.

To test this, I used the `CPUID` instruction, which returns the initial APIC ID of the current core in `EBX`:

```
void print_cpu() 
{
    int cpuid_out;

    __asm__(
    "cpuid;"
        : "=b"(cpuid_out) 
        : "a"(1) 
        :);

    std::cout << "I am running on cpu " << std::hex << (cpuid_out >> 24) << std::dec << std::endl;
}
```

Then I looped over the bits in the cpu mask and set them one at a time so that the OS would migrate the process to each logical CPU in turn, and then I printed out the current CPU.

This is what I got:

```
cpu mask is 0 
I am running on cpu 0
cpu mask is 1 
I am running on cpu 4
cpu mask is 2 
I am running on cpu 2
cpu mask is 3 
I am running on cpu 6
cpu mask is 4 
I am running on cpu 1
cpu mask is 5 
I am running on cpu 5
cpu mask is 6 
I am running on cpu 3
cpu mask is 7 
I am running on cpu 7
```

assuming that the CPU assigns initial APIC IDs according to the scheme I listed above, it would seem that the cpu mask doesn't actually correspond to the physical core and thread.

How can I find the correct mapping of bits in the mask for `sched_setaffinity` to physical cores?

Answer (score 2):

[hwloc](http://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/) is a portable C library for discovering hardware/NUMA topology, and also binding processes/threads to particular cores. It has functions to discover physical/logical cores, and then bind a process/thread to it.

It also [looks like](http://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/doc/v1.4/a00030_source.php) it can also return a `cpu_set_t` for use with `sched_setaffinity()`, if you want to keep using that directly.

Comment: One of hwloc's best features is the capability to show a diagram of the system topology -- how CPUs share caches, memory domains, etc.